# Difference between IQueryable.Cast<object>() and IQueryable.ToList<object>()

Tags: c#, linq

Can anyone explain what is the difference between IQueryable.Cast() and IQueryable.ToList() and which takes more time for converting in to object.

Comment: Couldn't you just read both documentations and then compare them?

Comment: Both are completely unrelated and do completely different things. You're comparing apples to oranges...

Comment: @JeffMercado More like comparing apples to trains

Answer (score 2):

`IQueryable.Cast<object>()` returns an enumerable collection of casted objects, while `IQueryable.ToList<object>()` enumerates through the collection and returns a new `List<object>` with all items casted to `object`.

`IQueryable.Cast<object>().ToList()` => `IQueryable.ToList<object>()`

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Which one takes more time . I measured this and Cast<object> takes more time compared to ToList<object> .

Comment: `ToList<object>` takes longer, because it has to cast AND create new List.

Comment: I am getting exception while using entities "Unable to cast the type 'ADO.NET_EntityDataModel_Binding.Order_Detail' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types." . Following code used in my application ,                    distinctRecords =
                                    filteredRecords.Cast<object>().Select(x => provider.GetValue(x, colName)).Distinct();                                                                Some of sites suggest to use ToList . Is there any other way to avoid this exception other than ToList<>()

Comment: @User, please start a new question on Stackoverflow for this exception. I believe your original question was answered.